# ActiveSupport::Concern vs model inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activesupport-concern

I want to share some behavior between several models. There are at least 2 approaches:

1) `ActiveSupport::Concern` :

```
module Contentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module InstanceMethods
    #some shared behavior(validations, callbacks, etc)
  end
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Contentable
end
```

2) model(class) inheritance:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base 
   #some shared behavior(validations, callbacks, etc)
end

class Article < Content  
end
```

The only advantage of the first one I see is that you are able to include as many modules as you wish
Are there other advantages/disadvantages of both approaches?

Comment: Another option would be to not add functionality to your models. If the models share several attributes, you may want to use inheritance/STI. However if it is actually functionality you are talking about adding, consider not putting it on the models at all and put it somewhere else like that classes that use the models.

Comment: your question is too broad. what is the actual use-case?

Comment: thanks for the responses. I mean not only attributes sharing, but another common features like callbacks, validations, etc, thus STI cannot be used. I've updated the answer to make it more understandable . Under 'classes that use models' you mean something like mix of both approaches depend on a case?